# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function validate() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.7, php, paypal, fatal-error

i am getting server error in magento 1.7

PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function validate() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php on line 137

How to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.7? I would advise upgrading to the latest 1.9 or closing the site as it will be hacked very soon.

The validate function on that line is called on either the billing or shipping address of the order.

`$address = $isOrderVirtual ? $order->getBillingAddress() : $order->getShippingAddress();`

So this suggests the address didn't' save correctly on the order. I would suggest taking a look at var/log system/log or exception.log. There would be an error explaining why this address could not be saved.